# If $Y$ and $Z$ are independent conditional on $X$, will $Y$ and $Z$ be independent of $W$ if $\sigma(W) \subset \sigma(X)$?

Tags: probability

If $Y$ and $Z$ are independent conditional on $X$, will this imply $Y$ and $Z$ be independent of another random variable $W$ if the sigma algebras of $W$ is a subset of the sigma algebra of $X$, such that

$$
\sigma(W) \subset \sigma(X)
$$

where $\sigma(W)$ is the sigma algebra of $W$ and $\sigma(X)$ is the sigma algebra of $X$?

Here, $Y$ and $Z$ independent conditional on $X$ is implied to mean:

$$
P(Y\mid Z,X) = P(Y \mid X)
$$

Comment: What do you mean by "independent conditional on $X$ ? that $\mathbb P\{Y\in A, Z\in B\mid X\in C\}=\mathbb P\{X\in A\mid X\in C\}\mathbb P\{Z\in B\mid X\in C\}$ ?

Comment: I added it in, I mean that $P(Y\mid Z,X) = P(Y \mid X)$